# Django - User created but Profile is missing

Tags: python, django, user-profile

When I register a new user, I can see from the Admin page that the user was created.
But whenever I go on my profile page in my nav bar I get the following Error.

[image]

[image]

It was actually working before I added a function on my Profile page (a button that deletes a user&profile) but I don't see what I need to page to fix this error.

profile.html

```
{% extends "digitalFarm/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
      <div class="content-section">
             <div class="media">
                    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
                    <div class="media-body">
                           <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                           <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
                    </div>
             </div>
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="boder-bottom mb-4">Profile info</legend>
                  {{ u_form|crispy }}
                  {{ p_form|crispy }}
                  {{ d_form|crispy }}
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update Profile</button>
              </div>
          </form>

          <form>
              {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Delete User Account</legend>
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger">
                      <a style="color: white" href="{% url 'profile_confirm_delete' %}">Delete Account</a></button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
    def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

def profile_confirm_delete(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {
        'user': user
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile_confirm_delete.html', context)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        print('delete works')
        return redirect('digitalFarm-home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form. is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else :
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("INSIDE CREATE_PROFILE")#negative
    if created:
        print("INSIDE CREATED_PROFILE")#negative
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs): #kwargs= accepts any additional keywords
        instance.profile.save()

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def delete_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs): #kwargs= accepts any additional keywords
        instance.profile.delete()
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

#Update
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    print("INSIDE ProfileUpdateForm")
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

#Delete
class ProfileDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

class UserDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []   #Form has only submit button.  Empty "fields" list still necessary, though.
```

Comment: I don't see `d_form` (`{{ d_form|crispy }}`) declared anywhere in your `profile` view. Where is that coming from?

Comment: I noticed that too, so I deleted it recently. It should be for deleting the profile. I thought that maybe I create but also delete it right after. But even after I deleted the d_ form the profiles were still missing.

Answer (score 1):

in your signals.py, I don't see any save() directive, how is your profile instance supposed to get in the DB, DB profile table is empty. You need something like this (for create):

```
Profile.objects.create(user=instance).save()
```

or actually

```
profileInstance = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
profileInstance.initNewProfile() # setup context default values
profileInstance.save()
```

Further more, on delete there is actually better option to delete dependent instance: CASCADE on ORM level. Has to be defined in class (models.py)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#create documents that `.objects.create` is a shortcut including the `.save` method. You shouldn't need to manually call `.save` after `.create`.

Comment: that was a good idea! I tried both ways but unfortunately it didn't worked... but I also assume that the create_profile method in signals won't be even entered as my terminal didn't print out anything

Comment: (1) it has to print the degug comment, else it does't trigger

Comment: if you delete an instance, there has to be point where you create explicit new one. Where is it. Your user create event triggers only once, when new user is created. your instance.profile.save(), if profile deleted, has no instance to save.

Comment: But there is not even a profile created when I create a user. Im not deleting any profile. But whenever I login and click on my profile page I get this error.

Comment: this is my guess. 

You have to see: @receiver(post_save, sender=User) is triggered always User is saved
(1) first time if USER is created,  and 
(2) all following saves (updates).

Profile instance is own entity, and User doesn't deal with it, you have to take care. Keep create one, but just  in case it doesn't exists; For my taste you need just one function

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
careForProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs)

and regardless user-create or update, if profile doesn't exist create one.